# How can I compare the current time with the next 10 seconds?

Tags: python, time

How can I compare the current time with the next 10 seconds?

e.g **in the current time, i post** a message to mqtt broker, and then **in next 10 secs automatically will post to mqtt broker again.**

Comment: Do you want to compare 2 different messages?

Comment: Why not use `sleep(10)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)?

Comment: Are you looking for [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait for 10 seconds before continuing on with your program?

Comment: Are there other solutions? I really avoid to using time.sleep() function

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand your question. But I think you want to do something now and do it in the next 10 seconds. If that's what you want, then,

```
import time
print("Do something")
time.sleep(10)
print("Do something")
```

Or if you want it do continuously, then:

```
import time
i = 0
while i < 10: #Using while loop for readability
    print("Do something")
    i = i + 1 # You can use i += 1 or i++
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `sleep`, compare the current `now` with your starting time + 10 seconds. Inside the loop you can do pretty much whatever you want.

```py
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


start_the_clock = datetime.now()
print ('now it is',start_the_clock)
end_the_clock = start_the_clock+timedelta(seconds=10)
print ('we will end at',end_the_clock)
ticker = r'\|/-'
t = 0
while datetime.now() < end_the_clock:
    print ('waiting... '+ticker[t & 3], end='\r')
    t += 1
print ('\nDone waiting at',datetime.now())
```

Comment: in my case, i want to use that comparison continously. e.g. every 10secs.. i can publish a message into message broker. can u help me to solve it?

Comment: @IdharDzulfikar: then wrap a loop around this entire routine.